# how to connect to WebSphere 7 admin console, or how to view error logs if it's not starting?

Tags: websphere

I have IBM RAD / WebSphere 7 installed locally.  My web application I'm developing runs fine.

I'm trying to log into the WAS admin console.

In the "Servers" view, I right-click the server > Administration > Run Administration Console ... but I get a "webpage cannot be found" error page.

In Firefox, I attempt to browse to the admin console URL, I tried each of the following but no luck:

```
http://localhost:9091/ibm/console/logon.jsp
http://localhost:9091/ibm/console/
http://localhost:9060/ibm/console/
http://localhost:9060/admin
```

Any ideas what the URL is?

Or, alternately, if the admin console is not starting due to some error, is there a log file somewhere where I can find the error?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The third of those would normally be the correct one, but the port number depends on what happened during the profile creation process. Find the profile directory and then look in the properties directory for the portdefs.props file. That will tell you what the correct port number should be.

It is possible to create a profile without the admin console application, in which case it will obviously never work. You could also try running wsadmin from the profile bin directory to see whether you can connect to the admin service that way.

Any errors from the admin console application will be reported in the normal log files in the profiles/profilename/logs/servername directory.

Comment: Thx!  Found `c:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\properties\portdefs.props`, says `WC_defaulthost=9080` and `WC_adminhost=9060`.  Tried connecting with `...\profiles\was70profile1\bin\wsadmin` and it appears to connect fine.  Does this mean `http://localhost:9060/ibm/console` should work?

Comment: Unless the admin console app wasn't installed for some reason, yes.

Try this:
wsadmin -lang jython -user <whatever> -password <whatever> then at the wsadmin prompt
AdminApp.list()

If it lists the admin console application along with the app you're testing then it should work, yes.

Comment: An `AdminApp.list()` results in: `'DefaultApplicaton\r\nIBMUTC\r\nJAXRSEAR\r\nivtApp\r\nquery'`  I don't know what that is, but my own web app is not installed, and it doesn't look like the admin console to me. :)  Does this mean I need to install the admin console?  If so, how do I do that?  (Thanks again for all the help!)

Comment: Try AdminApp.install("../installableApps/isclite.ear") followed by AdminConfig.save()

Comment: Before reading your instruction, I followed 'remove' and 'install' steps I found here http://eichelgartenweg2.blogspot.ca/2008/06/reinstall-admin-console-isclite.html and it appears to have worked!  Thanks for all the help, greatly appreciated!!

Comment: For the record, I did a: `/bin/wsadmin -lang jython -f deployConsole.py remove` and then a `/bin/wsadmin -lang jython -f deployConsole.py install` to get the console back.